# After strong impact my laptop's screen began showing artifacts but then returned to normal functionality, what was that?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, gpu, lenovo-laptop

Yesterday my PC was hit by a window and began showing various artifacts on the screen and flickering. My computer has insurance so I began a process to get a technician, but suddenly after a few hours artifacts began disappearing. Today they are completely gone.

So, should I continue with the technician or not? And what exactly was happening?

- Laptop model: **Lenovo T470**
- The video which shows how it looked: https://youtu.be/MBT-aCiWXMk

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that the connection knocked the connector loose and it got back so its secure enough to work. I wouldn't trust it as its probably still loose. You could check it by disassembling it, however if you have warranty then its probably worth your while to get it professionally looked at or replaced.

Historically (Well, I use a T430 and its the case here) all Thinkpads have freely available hardware maintenance manuals ([including yours](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t470_hmm_en_sp40m11890_03.pdf)) to disassemble it if you have the tools and experience, but from the T440 I've noticed that the ultrabook design has made it harder. So if you want to [check it out yourself](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t470_hmm_en_sp40m11890_03.pdf), you could try that, though if you have arranged a technician already i would continue. You don't want to be away from home or during a presentation and it decides to get knocked loose again.